# R Studio: pdf () failed to load default encoding and failed to load encoding file ISOLatin1.enc

Tags: python, r, pdf

First time poster with a question about RStudio.

I am following a tutorial to use a package called Plum in R (https://github.com/maquinolopez/Plum).

My system set-up on R is as follows:  R (3.5.1), with rPython (R package; Python 2.7), numpy (python package), scipy (python package), matplotlib (python package).

> library(devtools)
>
> install_github("maquinolopez/Plum")
>
> library(Plum)
>
> install.packages("rPython", configure.vars= "RPYTHON_PYTHON_VERSION=2")
>
> runPlum() #dummy dataset

When I runPlum(), which has a dummy dataset that I am working with to learn the package, the program works; however, I get the following errors every time:

```
Error in pdf(paste(folder, paste("Chronologylines ", Core.name, ".pdf",  : failed to load default encoding

In addition: Warning message: In pdf(paste(folder, paste("Chronologylines ", Core.name, ".pdf", : failed to load encoding file 'ISOLatin1.enc'
```

The result is that I cannot see the pdfs with the data plotted up -- very annoying!

I have tried putting pdf.options(encoding='ISOLatin1.enc') before I run Plum, to no avail.

I have tried manually putting UTI-8 in the encoding option before a run, which also did not fix anything.

Any tips on how to fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To help others helping you, please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You could start by adding an MCVE:     https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The help text you are looking for is hidden under `?postscript`:    `The file is looked for in the 'enc' directory of package ‘grDevices’ if the path does not contain a path separator.`

Comment: also worth noting that on most US-based and many European-based machines, ISOLatin1 is the default.  (meaning you can omit specifying the encoding)

Comment: Thanks Ricardo. I read the help text. I am still unsure what my steps should be to fix the problem -- can you clarify?